# phpmailer does not connect to SMTP servers

Tags: smtp, phpmailer

i've been trying to use phpmailer and tried using live.com and gmail.com but it always can't connect to SMTP server. here's the full code (i've tried live.com using smtp.live.com but i get the same problem "Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.")

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'my emil address';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'my password';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'the same email address';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
//$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('another email address');               // Name is optional
//$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
//$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
//$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
//$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
//$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because you've not set the port, and SMTPSecure should be lower case. Change this:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Beyond that, check that you're allowed to send outbound mail by your ISP/firewall and that your DNS is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587; //You have to define the Port
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
```

Remove This:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';
```