# Can't connect to SMTP server with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send an e-mail on my PHP script. Since mail() is disabled by my host, I had to use PHPMailer. I've set all the variables it needs. However I still can't send anything. I've tried a 3rd party website to test SMTP server and it worked. I've also tried to connect that SMTP server via Telnet but it gave me connection error as it did on PHP script.

I can't see anything about host in debug text. Did I set host in script with a wrong way? Lastly, host doesn't support TLS,SSL so I've set SMTPSecure to false.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
        try {
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 
            $mail->isSMTP();                           
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.myhost.com'; 
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                     
            $mail->Username = 'verify@mydomain.com';  
            $mail->Password = 'mypass';            
            $mail->SMTPSecure = false;              
            $mail->Port = 25;                      

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('verify@mydomain.com');
            $mail->addAddress('recipient@test.com');

            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
            $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

            $mail->send();
            echo 'Message has been sent';
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
```

And this is the debug text:

```
2018-02-27 11:05:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-02-27 11:05:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO mydomain.com
2018-02-27 11:05:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-02-27 11:05:59 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed: 
2018-02-27 11:05:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: HELO mydomain.com
2018-02-27 11:05:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-02-27 11:05:59 SMTP ERROR: HELO command failed: 
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
2018-02-27 11:05:59 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-02-27 11:05:59 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-02-27 11:05:59 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
SMTP connect() failed. 
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: did you see this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464326/phpmailer-does-not-connect-to-smtp-servers

Comment: I've looked to suggested answer for the question that you linked. My $mail->Port and $mail->SMTPSecure are correct. @RaheelAslam

Comment: are you sure that smtp is configured on your server and that you have specified the right host? and that smtp is reachable from outside and not only from localhost?

Comment: @RobertoBisello I've tested server with https://www.smtper.net and it worked perfectly. So I'm sure that I specified the right host and port.

Comment: There is something wrong with the server you are connecting to - it's opening a connection, but those `SERVER -> CLIENT` responses should not be empty, especially not the first one. Are you sure it's a mail server?

Comment: @Synchro As I told before I've tested server with smtper.net using same setting as my PHP code and it worked.

Comment: Does it show any more useful detail with `SMTPDebug = 4`?